# Debian Wheezy Losing video link on boot

Tags: boot, video, debian

I bought a small Intel Atom machine (Intel atom D525) and I've installed Debian Wheezy on it.

After I install (successfully) the OS (via USB) the machine boots and after a couple of seconds I lose video link. Here is what happens:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SbSvykUXIRk

**What I already tried:**

- Using different system architecture (since d525 supports 32 bit aswell as 64 bit OS) : i386 , amd64
- Using different installation supports: hd-media , dvd-1 cd-1
- Modifying the grub parameters adding one of the following *([as shown here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu))* : 
  `nomodeset acpi=off GRUB_GFXMODE=vga=vesa GRUB_GFXMODE=1024x768`

Here is how I set the various parameters:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/1v0muauk4resp05/2014-03-20%2019.36.26.jpg
https://www.dropbox.com/s/v5frd85u8c9kk77/2014-03-20%2019.35.02.jpg

Using live rescue mode:

- `/etc/fstab`: 
  https://www.dropbox.com/s/gh6kt1zakpyrhk1/2014-03-20%2019.49.34.jpg
- `lspci`: 
  https://www.dropbox.com/s/fvljb2l0wpmyg6o/2014-03-20%2019.50.09.jpg

I don't have X11 as I have not installed GUI.

Weird thing is that Debian 6 works just fine!
What may be the issue?

Comment: I believe I see COM1 and COM2 serial ports on the back of that machine. Your best bet for debugging is to use a serial console. Connect to another computer using a null modem cable, then add `console=/dev/ttyS0` to the boot line. I think the default is 9600-8-N-1. I think you can also add the rate to the end of that console line... its been a while.

Comment: BTW: I would *guess* that the kernel is activating the wrong port; perhaps its trying to use the HDMI port. If this is Intel video hardware (not sure what Atom uses), look at the i915 options.

Comment: I have already tried with i915.modeset=0 but with no result